# Trying to get a specific word and the word after/before said word in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to write a bot, and I ran into a problem that I cannot decide how to tackle.

For example, I have a string:

> "Today i will buy a set of buns for 4214 usd and eat it tomorrow."

How do I see if the string has "usd" in it, and if it is an int/float? If it does, how do I get the number that is near it?

The numbers may vary in their form, but general recognizable forms should be as follows:

- 1000
- -1000
- 1000.0
- -1000.0
- 1000,0
- -1000
- 0

Any further divisions into parts shouldn't be recognized.

For the string above, the expected result would be:

```
"4214 usd"
```

The regular expression would be useful here, but I am new and not familiar with them at all.

Comment: You should include what you think a valid number is. Is `0.1` a valid number? is `.1` a valid number? Is `1,000` a valid number? Is `1e6` a valid number? Is `-1000` a valid number? Is `1.000.000` a valid number? A regex doesn't have a concept of compound numbers so you should have specific criteria to match text against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is an acceptable tool,, if you can live with occasional false positives and false negatives (missed dollar amounts or things incorrectly marked as dollars).
Try this code. Since you're matching multiple formats within a string, it's hard to get all the matches at once.

See the explanations in the comment below what does the regex do.

The result will give you an array of strings, so you can process it. For example, iterate it and then remove  `usd` and turn them into JS numbers, so you could sum them or whatever.

```js
const text = `Today i will buy a set of buns for 4214 usd and eat it tomorrow. So tomorrow the budget would be total of -505.5 USD.`;

// regex to match "number USD"
const regex = /[-+]?\d+[,\.]?\d?\susd/gmi;
/*

[-+]?     # optional hyphen or plus sign
\d+       # followed by multiple numbers
[,\.]?    # followed by comma or dot, also optional
\d{1,2}?  # followed by one or two numbers, optional
\s        # followed by space
/gmi      # global, multiline, case insensitive flags: match all occurences in input data, ignore case

*/

// execute
const result = text.match(regex);


console.log('matches: ', result);


// now you can do something, for turn strings to numbers for sum or whatever..
result.forEach(res => {

  // turn it into a number or something
  const num = res.replace(/\susd/i, '').replace(',', '.');
  console.log(Number(num));

});
```

Comment: Why do you have `[^\d,\.]` before the sign? What if the sign is the first character (`[^\d,\.]` requires one character).

Comment: @PoulBak good point. it's a hack, not a good one, trying not to match `99,9999999 usd`, but match everything else...

Comment: Yes, that works.
Thanks a lot but also big thanks for explaining the actual regEx stuff!
Also , is it possible to replace the "usd" in the pattern using switch for example and how would that need to be written?

Comment: @Slendermanyshka not sure what you mean.. replace it with something else, other currency code, or remove it right away..?

Comment: @traynor yes for example changing the currency using switch or if/else.

Comment: @Slendermanyshka you could match it right away with `or` operator `|`, and by adding the currency. instead of `usd`, you'd add other currencies: `(usd|gbp|inr)`, so the final regex would be: `/[-+]?\d+[,\.]?\d?\s(usd|gbp|inr)/gmi`. then in the loop later, you can check which currency string includes, and perform different tasks, with switch or if. try the new regex, is that what you meant?

Comment: @traynoroh yea, makes sense, i didnt see the comment right away and here i am with a system which destringifies the regex and changes the currency according to some stuff, than turns it into a working regex again and gets the output

Comment: I wouldn't say that the regex is _the right tool_, but it's definitely one of the faster ones to implement. But as such, it's definitely have many edge cases to take care off. Matching these things on unstructured inputs will always be tricky. As long as the OP is aware of this and can accept the trade-off (occassional false positives or false negatives), this answer will work fine, with small tweaks over the time.

Answer (score 0):

.split

```js
let str = "Today i will buy a set of buns for 4214 usd and eat it tomorrow.";
let arr = str.split(" ");
if(arr.includes("usd")){
  arr.forEach(function(item,index){
    if(!isNaN(item)){
      console.log((item + " " + arr[index+1]));
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    import re

def extract_amount(text):
    pattern = r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)\s*(usd)'
    match = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
    
    if match:
        amount = match.group(1)
        currency = match.group(2)
        return f"{amount} {currency}"
    
    return None

text = "Today i will buy a set of buns for 4214 usd and eat it tomorrow."
result = extract_amount(text)
if result:
    print(result)
else:
    print("No amount found.")
```

You can use that code block

Comment: The question - as tagged - is looking for answers in JavaScript, to run under Node.js; this doesn't look like JavaScript however (though I freely admit that I'm in no way an expert in JavaScript), so doesn't seem to be an answer to the question within the constraints of the question.

Comment: The regEx patter does work in a regExr sim, ill try converting this to JS/node app